# if statement is printing even if it isn't true

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that checks if you're able to cross the border to Canada. For some reason, the first if statement prints even when it isn't true.

I've tried to add elif statements and indent the code but nothing has worked.

```
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    passport = input("Do you have a passport? ")
    if age >= 18 and "Yes" or "yes" in passport:
        print("You can cross the border to Canada.")
    if "No" or "no" in passport:
        enhanced_license = input("Do you have an enhanced license? ")
    if "Yes" or "yes" in enhanced_license:
        print("You can cross the border to Canada.")
    if age < 18:
        guardian = input("Are you traveling with a legal guardian? ")
            if guardian == "Yes" or "yes":
                print("You can cross the border to Canada.")
```

Everything works fine if you're 18 except the enhanced license part.
When I enter no for the passport this is the output of the code:

```
Enter your age: 18
Do you have a passport? no
You can cross the border to Canada.
Do you have an enhanced license?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed before, the line

```
if age >= 18 and "Yes" or "yes" in passport:
```

is responsible of that, and always evalued *True* if `age >= 18`, it's like

```
if age >= 18 and True or "yes" in passport:
```

You should rather lowercase the inputs for avoid a lot of conditional and error prone checks:

```
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
passport = input("Do you have a passport? ").lower()

if age >= 18 and "yes" in passport:
    print("You can cross the border to Canada.")
if "no" in passport:
    enhanced_license = input("Do you have an enhanced license? ").lower()
if "yes" in enhanced_license:
    print("You can cross the border to Canada.")
if age < 18:
    guardian = input("Are you traveling with a legal guardian? ").lower()
    if guardian == "yes":
        print("You can cross the border to Canada.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

```
if age >= 18 and "Yes" in passport or "yes" in passport:
```

Do it in other places too:

```
if "No" in passport or "no" in passport:
```

```
    if "Yes" in enhanced_license or "yes" in enhanced_license:
```

The operands of logical operators like `and` and `or` should always be Boolean expressions and "Yes" is not a Boolean expression and hence always evaluated to be `True`
In Python, strings and other sequences are evaluated to be `True` if it is non empty and is evaluated to `False` if empty.

Comment: True though your explanation about boolean expressions is not quite right and potentially misleading. `""` is not a boolean expression yet it is falsey, not truthy.

Comment: The exception only applies to empty sequences. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You could also just look at the first letter:

```
if age >= 18 and passport[0] == 'y':
```

This means you can accept 'yep' or 'yeah' or 'you betcha!' or 'ya gosh darn tootin' and so on. But seriously, some users may well think that 'y' is an appropriate response to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
if age>= 18 and "Yes" or "yes" in passport
```

to

```py
if age>=18 and "yes" in passport.lower()
```

This takes the lowercase of the passport string, and checks if the word "yes" is in it.

This will also work for strings like "yes, of course I do" or "of course YES", to avoid confusion I would use something like

```py
if age>18 and passport.lower()=="yes"
```

Also, instead of using `if "No" or "no" in passport` I would use else, which would only trigger if they didn't have a passport.

```py
else:
    ##your code here
```

The same works for the enhanced_license one:

```py
if age>=18 or enhanced_license.lower()=="yes"
```

The reason the original code didn't work is because the python "or" keyword only takes a Boolean value (true or false) so when presented with text it assumed it was true.